# How to take averages of NTiles in SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

edit: postgresql

I have a bunch of sales figures for some employees... table looks something like this:

```
    SalesRep    # of sales/day       NTILE(2)
    --------   --------------      ----------
    Johnny            1                  1
    Johnny            1                  1
    Johnny            4                  1
    Johnny            5                  2
    Johnny            5                  2
    Johnny            5                  2
    Sara              2                  1
    Sara              2                  1
    Sara              2                  1
    Sara              3                  2
    Sara              4                  2
    Sara              5                  2
    ...              ...               ...
```

I would like to find the average # of sales each rep makes per day on their 50% of the worst performing days, and also their 50% of  the best performing days

So for example, I would like the output table to look like this:

```
    SalesRep    #ofSales Bottom50%    #ofSales Top50%
    --------     --------------         ----------
    Johnny            2                  5
    Sara              2                  4
    ...             ...                ...
```

So far I have:

```
select 
    salesrep,
    case when ntile = 1 then avg(numsales) end,
    case when ntile = 2 then avg(numsales) end,
    ...
    ...
    case when ntile = 10 then avg(numsales) end

    from (

select 
    salesrep,
    numsales,
    NTILE(10) over (PARTITION BY salesrep order by numsales asc) as ntile
from XXX
    ) as YYY

group by salesrep, ntile
```

This is giving me a weird error where the output includes a bunch of NULLs... see table below:

```
    SalesRep     #ofSales Bottom50%    #ofSales Top50%
    --------     --------------         ----------
    Johnny            NULL                  5
    Sara               2                   NULL
    ...               ...                   ...
```

Comment: what is tile2 or ntile? are those ranking? or shortcut for percentile?

Comment: @Justin: can't be MySQL because it still doesn't support window functions. and can't be SQL Server as it does not have the `ntile()` function. I guess it's Oracle.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name oh yeah I see now

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - point of order - SQL Server has had `NTILE()` since SQL 2005 - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175126.aspx

Comment: @EdHarper: ah! thanks, I checked the manual but I missed that ;)

Answer (score 1):

One row in your desired output represents a single `SalesRep` – therefore, you must group by `SalesRep` *only*. And the `case` expressions would then go *inside* the `avg` calls as their arguments, like this:

```
select 
    salesrep,
    avg(case when ntile = 1 then avg(numsales) end),
    avg(case when ntile = 2 then avg(numsales) end),
    ...
    ...
    avg(case when ntile = 10 then avg(numsales) end)

from (
    select 
        salesrep,
        numsales,
        NTILE(10) over (PARTITION BY salesrep order by numsales asc) as ntile
    from XXX
) as YYY

group by salesrep, ntile
;
```

or, rewriting the above without all that fancy formatting:

```
select 
    salesrep,
    avg(case when ntile = 1 then numsales end),
    avg(case when ntile = 2 then numsales end),
    ...
    ...
    avg(case when ntile = 10 then numsales end)

from (
    select 
        salesrep,
        numsales,
        NTILE(10) over (PARTITION BY salesrep order by numsales asc) as ntile
    from XXX
) as YYY

group by salesrep
;
```